# Start XTerm with custom bash history

Tags: bash, command-history, xterm

Can I start `xterm` with a custom bash history including a list of predefined commands? So that I can run several `xterm`, where each instance has his own history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make a file `~/myhistory` with the commands you want in the history, one per line
2. `chmod a-w ~/myhistory`, [so that Bash won't try to change it](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities). If you *want* the commands the user enters to be written back (to that same file), skip this step.
3. `HISTFILE=~/myhistory xterm -e bash` [to make Bash load history data from](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-HISTFILE) `~/myhistory`. If your default shell is `bash` then you can lose the `-e bash`.

Within the shell the command history will be what you wrote in the file, accessible through the up arrow, history expansion, the `fc` command, or any other way you get to the history.

---

If you can't make a real file, this fairly-hacky workaround will work as well:

```
HISTFILE=<(printf '%s\n' command1 "second 'command here'" 3rd) xterm -e bash
```

This uses [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) to generate a file-like entity for the shell to read from, with the output of the [`printf` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf) as the contents. This `printf` will print out each of the arguments, one per line. You'll have to quote things carefully to make sure that the commands as output are in the format you need.

Comment: Does this also work, if I want to start several `xterm`, where each has his own history file?

Comment: As long as you use a different file for each one, yes.

Comment: So I can set (override) the environment variable `HISTFILE` for each `bash` instance when they run simultaneously without loosing the link between one `bash` instance and their history file?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.